# FlashDevelop compiling Type was not found DatagramSocket

Tags: flash, flashdevelop, datagram

I getting this error(s) when I'm trying to compile Adobe's UDP socket example:
- Definition flash.net:DatagramSocket could not be found.

I am using these software:
FlashDevelop IDE 4.3.0,
Adobe AIR SDK 3.6, Flex 4.6.0; (installed with FlashDevelop)

Project properties:
Platform - Flash Player 10.3,
Compilation mode - Application,
ActionScript 3

Am I missing something? How to get it work?

EDIT: Reference used in my project:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-7ffe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding import at the beginning of your code:

```
import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you create AIR project and not simple AS3 project? Because example from that link compiled good for me, when I setted up AIR project in FlashDevelop

Comment: And also DatagramSocket will not be available in AIR for mobile devices.

Comment: You are right! I had set a simple AS3 project. That's why I had these errors. Now it works! Thanks for your help! (P.S. I'm newbie in flash)